# How to prevent reverse proxying on certain ports (mod_proxy)?

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, mod-proxy, vhosts

I am using apache to proxy to tomcat webapps, which works fine. I previously had tomcat listen directly on :8080, so I would like to inform users of my webapp of the move. To that end, I defined a vhost to listen to 8080 where a static html page should be served with the new link.  To that end, I defined the following vhost:

```
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost domain.example.com:8080
<VirtualHost domain.example.com:8080>
   ProxyPass /webapp !
   DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/vhost-8080
</VirtualHost>
```

Where the directory vhost-8080 has an index.html with the new link in it.

But every time I load domain.example.com:8080/webapp, I am directed towards tomcat and the webapp, even though domain.example.com:8080/ loads the index.html file I put in the vhost-8080 directory. How can I prevent proxying on this port and only enable it on 80?

For the sake of completeness, here's my proxy configuration:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy ajp://localhost/webapp >
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from none
   Allow from all
</Proxy>
<Location /webapp>
   ProxyPass ajp://localhost:18009/webapp timeout=1200
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/webapp
</Location>
```

Tomcat has ajp connector enabled and http connector disabled.